# Cube with diffuse light always black

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I have an simple Opengl-Application like this :
[image]

As you can see i have a plane and suzanne with a texture and also some light.But there is aslo an cube.You can see just the upper half, but the problem ist that the cube stays black, no matter what.I tried to apply a texture --> black.I tried to give the cube just a color ---->still black.

```
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector;
smooth in vec2 textureCords;


out vec4 outputColor;


uniform sampler2D s;
uniform int hasTexture;
uniform vec3 LightColor;


void main()
{
   vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
   vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);
   float ndot = dot(unitNormal,unitLightVector);
   float brightness = max(ndot,0.0);
   vec3 diffuse = brightness*LightColor*1.5;
    if(hasTexture == 1){

        **outputColor =  vec4(diffuse,1.0) * texture(s,textureCords);**
    }else{

        **outputColor = vec4(diffuse,1.0) *vec4(0.4,0.5,0.7,1.0);**
    }
}
```

This is my fragment shader.I pass this shader a uniform hasTexture to check if it should be rendered with texture or without.
For example :

```
cube.draw("texture.png");
```

or

```
cube.draw();
```

Since this method i use works with the two other models, i really dont know whats the problem  with it.Maybe the texture-coordinats are wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest verifying that the problem is indeed in the texture, in other words, eliminate the possibility that hasTexture might not be 1, your diffuse might be 0, etc. Also check your texture, if your texture does not contain black, the sampler will not ever return black, even if the coordinates dont make sense. Also, why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Based off of the given information, my guess is that brightness is 0 because the ndot is either 0 or negative. I would say check your normals and your 'toLightVector's. Even if your texture coordinates were wrong, setting the cube to a color should have worked.